# Difference between autocomplete and ajax?

Tags: ajax, autocomplete

What is the diffrence between Ajax and autocomplete function.
I know autocomplete is a software function that completes words or strings without the user needing to type them in full.
Ajax is similar to it + other functions.

Comment: actually, I think many web autocomplete functions are implemented using ajax :-)

Comment: autocomplete = feature. ajax = technology.

Answer (score 2):

AJAX stands for "Asynchronous JavaScript and XML" and offers an alternative to the traditional "request-respond-cicle".

With AJAX you can get data from the server without your browser having to re-render the whole page.

Autocomplete on the other hand side mostly uses AJAX to get possible results on every key hit by the users.

Read more about AJAX here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete works only using data suggestions from the cache, Ajax works using data suggestions from the server in addition to the data from the cache.

Using Ajax, we can render certain parts of a web page without a rendering the whole web page, which significantly reduces the network bandwidth.

Comment: Thank you very much for the expanation !